# Physics Trick Needed

Tags: box2d, physics, game-physics

I am getting this problem while adding features to my game boss .
One of the attack boss will perform ,is  jumping from it's initial postion to directly on players body (Hurting him). Now I am not getting the idea how to set the initial velocity of boss so that it will jump on player's body always. We have two factors Boss position and Player Position (End Point).Any Formula/suggestions will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: There is more than one way to jump from A to B. Do you want the boss to jump to the same height every time? Or launch at the same angle? Or the same initial speed? Or land at a particular angle?

Comment: The only constraint is height , it will look good and decent to have same height every time .Is it possible with A & B known while jumping.

Comment: Same height above A? Or above B? Or above the origin? And do you want the velocity in x and y components, or magnitude and angle?

Comment: I want it like projectile motion , with maximum height always constant    , so it's going to need velocity in both x & y component .

Comment: @Beta is there anything i can do in that situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the vertical part.

Conventions: up is the positive direction, and g is positive.

To start from A<sub>y</sub> and reach maximum height H requires an initial velocity **V<sub>y</sub>=sqrt(2g(H-A<sub>y</sub>))**.

The time to reach this height and then fall back down to B<sub>y</sub> is **t=sqrt(2/g) (sqrt(H-A<sub>y</sub>)+sqrt(H-B<sub>y</sub>))**.

Now we can do the horizontal part. To get from A<sub>x</sub> to B<sub>x</sub> in the time t, we must have a (constant) horizontal velocity **V<sub>x</sub> = (B<sub>x</sub>-A<sub>x</sub>)/t**.